# Angular Unit testing for Safe Pipe

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a unit testing case without using fixtures. But it keep throwing me an error

I am getting an error of

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl is not a function
```

```
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: string): SafeResourceUrl {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
  }
```

```
  it('should return safe url', () => {
    const pipe = new SafeUrlPipe(<DomSanitizer>{});
    pipe.transform('val');
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I have try too make it undefined or match but it still haven't work

Answer (score 0):

You're providing a stubbed DomSanitizer with `<DomSanitizer>{}`. On this object, your pipe is trying to call `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`, but this is not defined.

Change your spec to define the stub like this:

```
const stub = { bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value) { return value; } };
const pipe = new SafeUrlPipe(stub as unknown as DomSanitizer);
```

Comment: Conversion of type '{ bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value: string): string; }' to type 'DomSanitizer' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value: string): string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'DomSanitizer': sanitize, bypassSecurityTrustHtml, bypassSecurityTrustStyle, bypassSecurityTrustScript, bypassSecurityTrustUrl

Comment: I get that errors

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to a working example, so I can't try it out. I've edited the code in my reply, can you please try it again?